# ¿Consumir servicio web con PHP?

Tags: php, json, xml, webservice, rest

Necesito consumir datos a través de GET y POST a un servicio web, esta operación la tengo que hacer desde PHP. Mi duda es, ¿cuáles son los componentes que necesito para poder hacer este consumo? o ¿algún ejemplo básico de como se hace esto?

Comment: Una consulta Jhonathan, como resolviste el problema. Graci

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5oLDQB ,Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera ,espero te ayude,saludos.

Comment: @JonathanRiveraDiaz Si alguna de las respuestas resolvió tu duda/problema, márcala para apoyar a los demás a conocer la solución, si ninguna la resolvió y conseguiste la solución, podrías responder tu pregunta y marcarla como la solución.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para consumir el API Rest Puedes usar este Código:

```
<?php
    class CurlRequest
    {
        public function sendPost()
        {
            //datos a enviar
            $data = array("a" => "a");
            //url contra la que atacamos
            $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/API/post");
            //a true, obtendremos una respuesta de la url, en otro caso, 
            //true si es correcto, false si no lo es
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            //establecemos el verbo http que queremos utilizar para la petición
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            //enviamos el array data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
            //obtenemos la respuesta
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            // Se cierra el recurso CURL y se liberan los recursos del sistema
            curl_close($ch);
            if(!$response) {
                return false;
            }else{
                return $response;
            }
        }

        public function sendPut()
        {
            //datos a enviar
            $data = array("a" => "a");
            //url contra la que atacamos
            $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/WebService/API_Rest/api.php");
            //a true, obtendremos una respuesta de la url, en otro caso, 
            //true si es correcto, false si no lo es
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            //establecemos el verbo http que queremos utilizar para la petición
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            //enviamos el array data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
            //obtenemos la respuesta
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            // Se cierra el recurso CURL y se liberan los recursos del sistema
            curl_close($ch);
            if(!$response) {
                return false;
            }else{
                var_dump($response);
            }
        }

        public function sendGet()
        {
            //datos a enviar
            $data = array("a" => "a");
            //url contra la que atacamos
            $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/WebService/API_Rest/api.php");
            //a true, obtendremos una respuesta de la url, en otro caso, 
            //true si es correcto, false si no lo es
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            //establecemos el verbo http que queremos utilizar para la petición
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
            //enviamos el array data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
            //obtenemos la respuesta
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            // Se cierra el recurso CURL y se liberan los recursos del sistema
            curl_close($ch);
            if(!$response) {
                return false;
            }else{
                var_dump($response);
            }
        }

        public function sendDelete()
        {
            //datos a enviar
            $data = array("a" => "a");
            //url contra la que atacamos
            $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/WebService/API_Rest/api.php");
            //a true, obtendremos una respuesta de la url, en otro caso, 
            //true si es correcto, false si no lo es
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            //establecemos el verbo http que queremos utilizar para la petición
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            //enviamos el array data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
            //obtenemos la respuesta
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            // Se cierra el recurso CURL y se liberan los recursos del sistema
            curl_close($ch);
            if(!$response) {
                return false;
            }else{
                var_dump($response);
            }
        }
    }

    $new = new CurlRequest();

    $resultado = $new ->sendPost();
    var_dump($resultado);
```

Comment: ya quedo resuelto,como puedo dar por terminada la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esto te pueda servir.

Si tu webservice  te devuelve resultados en XML

```
<?php
  // Llamada al WebService
  $client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL");
  $result = $client->GetCountries();
  $xml = $result->GetCountriesResult;

  // procesar xml
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
  foreach($xml->Table as $table) 
  {
    $output .= "<p>$table->Name</p>";
  }
  print_r($output);
?>
```

Si tu webservice devuelve resultados en JSON

```
<?php
// Función para llamar al webservice y devolver el resultado en un array
function callWebService($method)
{
  $url ='http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo';
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $array = json_decode($json,true);
  return $array;
}
```

Esa misma función puede optimizarse en una sóla línea:

```
function callWebService($method)
{
  return json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo'),true);;
}
```

La llamada podría ser de la siguiente manera:

```
$resul = callWebService();
foreach($resul['geonames'] as $city)
{
    $cities .= '<p>'.$city['name'].'</p>';    
}
print_r ($cities);
```

---

// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: ok mas o menos entiendo,soy totalmente nuevo en esto,pero por ejemplo noto que en lo que me explicaste,el web service es en soap,en mi caso estoy tratando con un rest,y tambien me parece ser,que ahi solo se recibe datos,o me equivoco? , yo tengo que hacer una peticion y recibir una respuesta

Comment: Ok. Te agrego una función para mayor información, si ya tienes código agrégalo y te podemos ayudar.

Comment: todavia no tengo nada de código,en cuanto lo tenga o subire,y perdon que siga molestando ,pero esto me sirve para rest?

Comment: Claro, es una función para rest. Si tienes duda, preguntanos, todos podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Estoy tratando de cargar mi codigo aqui pero no me deja,tengo un codigo practicamente listo,ahora el problema es que no me deja ,el xampp me marca esto: Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\consulta\consulta.php on line 4,no encuentra la clase y copie todo,e intente con rutas relativas